# OFFSET and FETCH NEXT in sql: Can't return less number of record than the limit

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to know if it is possible to return a number of records less than the number specified in Fetch next
Here is my code in oracle sql:

```
SELECT
    code,
    english_desc,
    french_desc,
    arabic_desc
FROM
    xxisf_icd10
 
WHERE
    code LIKE nvl(:CODE, CODE) and ENGLISH_DESC LIKE NVL(:ENG_DESC,ENGLISH_DESC) 
    and FRENCH_DESC LIKE NVL(:Fr_desc,FRENCH_DESC) 
    and (ARABIC_DESC like nvl(:ARABIC_DESC, ARABIC_DESC) or ARABIC_DESC is null)
order by english_desc offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

However, when I do a like search On code, it must return one record, but does not return nothing.
So I would like to know if it is normal or not.
Thank you!!

Comment: If this query returns one row (as you said), what's the purpose of `offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only `? Remove it entirely.

Comment: It's not clear what is your issue? Provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If your where filters are not true for any row in your table then there's no row that could be returned, no matter how many you limit the fetch for.